# What happens if I get upvoted but have already reached the daily limit?

Tags: discussion, policy

The title says it all. I reached my daily limit today and noticed that one of my questions was upvoted *after* I reached the daily limit.

What happens to the reputation? Do I get it tomorrow or is it lost into the ether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Receiving upvotes after hitting the rep cap have do not alter your reputation, neither at the moment nor at a later date.

From [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/170332):

> You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes and suggested edits in any given [day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start). Bounties and the bonuses for accepted answers are counted separately ([source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/)). **Reputation “lost” from the reputation cap is not awarded on following days.**

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

See also: [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap)

Comment: Well that's a shame!

Comment: @ThisGuy On the other hand, you [got a badge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/25/mortarboard?userid=66833) for it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a bit to the main answer: upvotes you receive beyond the rep cap are not entirely useless, as they'll cancel out subsequent unupvotes on an upvote you receive that day. (That is, when you get unupvoted, it's as though the original upvote never happened; but if you had "extra" upvotes that day, some of them can cover.)

Comment: To add a little bit onto this answer.  They do not cancel out other rep loosing actions like casting a downvote, receiving a downvote or bountying a question.  However if you do drop below the 200 threshold due to one of these you will keep your progress towards Mortarboard/Epic/Legendary. Whether they affect unaccepts I don't know, I have never unaccepted when I was over 200 rep for the day.